# stack name with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

Is there a way to set the stack name when using docker-compose?

Currently it takes the folder name (which is a horrible area) and that leads to some confusion.

For example, we have several projects that have a database folder that contains the database stack. When running these on a single host, we have now several database stacks.

Comment: The project name can be set using the `name: my-project` top level element in the docker-compose file. See answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888090/4632019)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

**1. Using `--project-name` (or `-p`) option when calling `docker-compose`:**

`docker-compose -p "my-app" up`

> Caution: `-p "my-app"` must come before `up`.

**2. COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable:**

```
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my-app
docker-compose up
```

**3. COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME in .env file**

Create a file named **.env** in the project root and set the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable there:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=some_app
```

and then:

```
docker-compose up
```

> The **.env** file is read from the folder **where the docker-compose command
> is executed**, NOT from the folder of the docker-compose.yml file.

Assuming the following project structure:

```
root
 - database
   - docker-compose.yml
   - .env
 - app
   - docker-compose.yml
   - .env
 - ...
```

The command below, executed in the root folder, will not give desired effects:

```sh
# Stack name 'database' (the folder name). The root/database/.env file not read.
docker-compose -f ./database/docker-compose.yml up
```

The docker-compose command needs to be executed in the root/database folder:

```sh
# Stack name from the root/database/.env
cd database
docker-compose up
```

> If you use option 2 or 3, the project name is applied to all docker-compose commands, as if it were specified with the `-p` option.

Comment: It is just so upsetting you can't set it in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Related: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name

Comment: @disfated: Now this is possible with `name: my-project` top level element in the docker-compose file. See answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888090/4632019)

Comment: @Mafor your answer is very comprehensive, kudos on that.. but can you please also update it with the "`name` in `docker-compose`" option mentioned in the comments above?

Answer (score 17):

It looks like the project name can be set using the `name` top level element in the docker-compose file as described here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/04-version-and-name/#name-top-level-element

> Top-level `name` property is defined by the specification as project name to be used if user doesn’t set one explicitly. Compose implementations MUST offer a way for user to override this name, and SHOULD define a mechanism to compute a default project name, to be used if the top-level `name` element is not set.

This doesn't seem to be well documented anywhere else, and I didn't see a reference to it in the spec changelog, so I'm not sure if this has always been part of the spec, or if compose just didn't support it until recently.

The level of precedence for the project name is documented here:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name

---

**Example**

My current directory (`pwd`):

```
/Users/brahmlower/development/compose-test
```

My compose file (`cat docker-compose.yml`):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

name: my-project

services:
  hello-world:
    image: "hello-world:latest"
```

Without the `name` property, we would expect to see the stack started with the prefix `compose-test` since that's the name of the directory. However when I bring the stack up, we see compose names the stack `my-project` as expected.

The stack output (`docker compose up -d`):

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network my-project_default          Created
 ⠿ Container my-project-hello-world-1  Started
```

---

**Versions**

In case it's helpful, my docker versions are:

compose (`docker compose version`):

```
Docker Compose version v2.10.2
```

docker (`docker version`):

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:04:45 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:01 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.8
  GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: Indeed, IntelliJ was giving a highlight error on it, but it does work

Comment: @DavidGomes I found that it was an error because of the version. At first, I was using `version: "3.3"` by changing it to `version:"3.8"` (you can set it above 3.4) the highlighted error disappeared.