# How to deploy multiple databases with one docker-compose.yml using env variables?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: "container_${DB_NAME}"
    image: mysql:5
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
```

And this is my `.env.development` (one of my .env files):

```
PORT=3000
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=db_dev
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I use to deploy db service with `docker-compose --env-file .env.development up` and it works perfectly.

However, if I want to deploy another db service at the same time with another .env file (with for example `docker-compose --env-file .env.production up`), the first one is stopped and this is the message I get:

```
Recreating container_db_dev ... done
Attaching to container_db_prod
```

So my question is, can I use one docker-compose.yml like this one and deploy multiple database services depending on .env given file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-p` command to specific your compose stack name.

`docker-compose -p "new_stack" --env-file .env.production up`

The answer I get from [stack name with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401672/stack-name-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Thanks! It tries to create another service as expected but mysql port (3306) is already in use... It says `Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated`

Comment: One port can only bind to 1 container/service. You can change the `DB_PORT` in your env file right.

Comment: Oh I thought it was because of mysql static port. I changed `DB_PORT` in `.env.production` and now I have the two containers up. Thanks a lot!